# How to measure Accuracy

Tags: error

I want to measure the accuracy of my GPS Receiver module. The real coordinates are obtained from the Google Maps, and the actual received coordinates are the ones that the GPS receiver received. I tried searching for statistical tools that can somehow support my findings. I tried using Chi-square test in Microsoft Excel, but I don't know how to interpret the results. How do I interpret the result? Or what statistical tool is really fit for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what you trying to do here, but you given the GPS coordinates from your devices and those from Google Maps you could then calculate for each pair of coordinates how far the two sets are apart, so that you have an error in meters. How to calculate the distance between a pair of GPS coordinates was answered on StackExchange some time ago:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates

Based on the meter values you could then calculate the mean error in meters or the median error in meters.

I would also look into how accurate the Google Maps coordinates are. Otherwise you are just investigating how well your device agrees with Google Maps and how accurate it really is.